# Python Arping Code Not Working

Tags: python, scapy, arp

I have the following code, which gives the MAC and IP addresses of the local network. However, the code is not consistent, as sometimes devices that are connected appear, and then after a couple of seconds they disappear from the results.

I can't understand why!

Here is the code:

```
import logging
logging.getLogger("scapy.runtime").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
from scapy.all import arping
import time

def sniffer():
    res = arping("192.168.2.*")
    mac = '91:b7:66:cd:d6:7n'
    print check_MAC(res, mac)

def check_MAC(res, mac):
    for r in res[0]:
        if r[1].src == mac:
            return "MAC found!"
        return "MAC not found..."

while (True):
    sniffer()
    time.sleep(30)
    print""
```

Comment: I still haven't been able to understand why the scanning does not give the same results every time. Can someone share a tip??